# How to use the downloaded bootstrap files

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grails, gsp

I download the files from the bootstrap site. I then moved the files into my project css and js folders. I linked them and it doesn't work. I tried it with the cdn and it works fine with that.

Here is my code:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image]

Comment: What does your directory structure look alike?

Comment: I put a picture of it

Comment: And what file is currently open? UrlMappings.groovy contains the line `<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">`? I'm not familiar to the groovy scene, but you will need to use a path like: `../../web-app/css/bootstap-min.css`. Instead you could also use the absolute path to your `bootstrap.min.css` file.

Comment: Which version of grails are you using? You could take an advantage of either resource plugin or assets-pipeline plugin based on your grails version

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem lies in the fact that u use:

```
/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

The first `/` indicates the root folder of your current drive, which I believe does not contain the css directory.

More particularly:

- / means the root of the current drive;
- ./ means the current directory;
- ../ means the parent of the current directory.

You should link to the correct path (absolute or relatively) of your css file. It would be a lot more probable that you need to use `../css/bootstrap.min.css` or `css/bootstrap.min.css`, depending on your directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Twitter Bootstrap with the Asset-Pipeline. The steps are...

1. Create the directory *grails-app/assets/bootstrap*
2. Copy the Twitter Bootstrap **css**, **fonts**, and **js** directories into the directory created in step 1. You should have a path like this, for example: *grails-app/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css*
3. Create the file *grails-app/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.css* with the contents:

   +/*

   +*= require css/bootstrap.min

   +*= require css/bootstrap-theme.min

   +*/
4. Create the file *app/grails-app/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.js* with the contents:

   +//= require js/bootstrap.min
5. Add the follwing to *app/grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js*

   //= require bootstrap
6. Add the following to *app/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/application.css*

   *= require bootstrap
7. Make sure your GSP or the layout it uses pulls in the assets using the *asset:stylesheet* and *asset:javascript* tags. (This step may already done):

Comment: I wanted to add that code but StackOverflow rejected it. If you go to http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#linking under the Views section you'll see two tags from the Asset-Pipeline TagLibrary. Those two tags process the application.js and application.css files. You'll need those two tags added either to the layout used by you GSP or in the GSP itself.

Comment: I followed your instructions and the bootstrap didn't load the page correctly

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "bootstrap didn't load the page correctly". Take a look at this changeset: https://bitbucket.org/erosa/masteringgrails3/commits/8305eef8326764ab30f063477a2940fb6dfc3ea5?at=default It adds Twitter Bootstrap to a Grails 3 project, a project which already had the Asset-Pipeline plugin.

Comment: sorry I didn't word it correctly. When the page loads the bootstrap <navbar navbar-inverse> and stuff like that doesn't display

Comment: The Bootstrap is not loading. Since you're using Grails 2.x, check grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy and make sure you've got `compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"` in your plugins section. Note your version may be slightly different. Also check your changes against the changeset I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I'm seeing compile ":asset-pipeline:2.1.5"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86735/discussion-between-emmanuel-rosa-and-taylor-gagne).

Answer (score 1):

try this one..

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using the gsp way of finding a file path.

It's supposed to look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'bootstrap.min.css')}" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Include path before **/bootstrap.min.css** and **/bootstrap.min.js**
Like this 
In My case:

```
<link href="D:/ZIA/Semester 6b/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" >
     <script src="D:/ZIA/Semester 6b/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```